# Mocks are not returning values properly with mockitoextension.class (Junit5)

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So i have this code, where im trying to mock that atendees receive the notifications:

```
 @Mock
    Event event;

    @Mock
    Attendee attende;

    @InjectMocks
    EventNotificationServiceImpl eventNotificationService;

    @Test
    public void checkIfAttendesAreNotified() {

        event.addAttendee(attende);

        eventNotificationService.announce(event);

        System.out.println(attende.getNotifications());

        List<Notification> notifications = attende.getNotifications();

        for (Notification notification : notifications) {

            assertEquals("The next big event is coming!", notification.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

however here i dont see that atendees receive any notifications.But when I put this code, i see attendes receive notifications:

```
  @Mock
    Event event;

    @Mock
    Attendee attende;

    @InjectMocks
    EventNotificationServiceImpl eventNotificationService;

    @Test
    public void checkIfAttendesAreNotified() {
        attende = new Attendee(1L,"sara", "sara@example.com");
        event = new Event();
        event.addAttendee(attende);

        eventNotificationService.announce(event);

        System.out.println(attende.getNotifications());

        List<Notification> notifications = attende.getNotifications();

        for (Notification notification : notifications) {

            assertEquals("The next big event is coming!", notification.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Id like to know why mocks are not being inicitialized. Id like to not have to create the event and attendees objects in the tests since this bring me problems cause when i try to verify, attendees and events are not recognized as mocks. If someone can help me Id be very thankful! :)))

Answer (score 0):

You didn't stub any method call on `event` and `attendee` mocks.
Therefore, Mockito applies its default behaviour for unstubbed methods - it returns the default value, according to method return type.

See [How about some stubbing?](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.8.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing)

> By default, for all methods that return a value, a mock will return either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and false for a boolean/Boolean.

Thus, your test behaves as follows:

```
// Do nothing - return value ignored
event.addAttendee(attende);

// Do nothing - return value ignored
eventNotificationService.announce(event);

// Print empty list
System.out.println(attende.getNotifications());

// Store empty list in a variable
List<Notification> notifications = attende.getNotifications();

// Loop over empty list
for (Notification notification : notifications) {
    assertEquals("The next big event is coming!", notification.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: but i dont want to change atendee return values, i just want to initialize attendee that is an object with custom values,...dunno if has sense do it with stubbing?

Comment: No, you typically mock collaborators of object under test that have behaviours you don't want in your test (like http requests, db request, long computations etc). For objects that are simple to construct and have no unwanted behaviours, you are better off using the real object.